# rethinkdb: group documents by price range

Tags: group-by, aggregate, rethinkdb

I want to group documents in rethinkdb by price range (0-100, 100-200, 200-300, and so on), instead of a single price value. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, ReQL doesn't support rounding at the moment ([see github issue #866](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/866)), but you can get something similar through some minor annoyances.

First of all, I would recommend making this an index on the given table if you're going to be running this regularly or on large data sets.  The function I have here is not the most efficient because we can't round numbers, and an index would help mitigate that a lot.

These code samples are in Python, since I didn't see any particular language referenced.  To create the index, run something like:

```
r.db('foo').table('bar').index_create('price_range',
    lambda row: row['price'].coerce_to('STRING').split('.')[0].coerce_to('NUMBER')
                   .do(lambda x: x.sub(x.mod(100)))).run()
```

This will create a secondary index based on the price where `0` indicates `[0-100)`, `100` is `[100-200)`, and so on.  At this point, a group-by is trivial:

```
r.db('foo').table('bar').group(index='price_range').run()
```

If you would really rather not create an index, the mapping can be done during the `group` in a single query:

```
r.db('foo').table('bar').group(
    lambda row: row['price'].coerce_to('STRING').split('.')[0].coerce_to('NUMBER')
                   .do(lambda x: x.sub(x.mod(100)))).run()
```

This query is fairly straight-forward, but to document what is going on:

- `coerce_to('STRING')` - we obtain a string representation of the number, e.g. `318.12` becomes `"318.12"`.
- `split('.')` - we split the string on the decimal point, e.g. `"318.12"`. becomes `["318", "12"]`.  If there is no decimal point, everything else should still work.
- `[0]` - we take the first value of the split string, which is equivalent the original number rounded down. e.g. `"318"`.
- `coerce_to('NUMBER')` - we convert the string back into an integer, which allows us to do modulo arithmetic on it so we can round, e.g. `"318"` becomes `318`.
- `.do(lambda x: x.sub(x.mod(100)))` - we round the resulting integer down to the nearest 100 by running (essentially) `x = x - (x % 100)`, e.g. `318` becomes `300`.